# C# to Java

Tags: c#, java, конвертер

У меня есть пару классов, написанных на C#.

Есть ли конвертер, который переведёт эти классы на Java?

В классе у меня никаких сторонних сборок не используется, есть индексатор и определённые операторы +, -, ==. Понятно, что в Java нет перегрузки операторов, но их можно и не преобразовывать из C#, их можно вообще опустить.

**UPD**: Грубо говоря: конвертеру на вход скармливают файлы .cs, а он на выходе даёт .java

Comment: сколько там файлом? это не проблема сделать ручками, проблемы могут быть только с инициализацией массива, выводом на консоль и не которыми классами, если они используются вообще, потому поправь сам и все должно работать.

Comment: Ручками все делаете, ручками. Тем более, что пару классов перевести не проблема.

Comment: В том-то и проблема - классов штук 15!!! Это я писал математическую библиотеку, просто подумал "запортить" её на Android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обсуждение на SOF: [Is there an effective tool to convert C# code to Java code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78811/is-there-an-effective-tool-to-convert-c-sharp-code-to-java-code)

[Tangible C# to Java Converter](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/CSharp_to_Java_Converter_Details.html)

Comment: Чисто любопытно — а наоборот бывает?

Comment: Бывает. 

- [Source Code Converters][1]
- [Java Language Conversion Assistant][2] - отличная штука


  [1]: http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/
  [2]: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=14349

Comment: Спасибо, @mantigatos, отличные ссылки, наверняка где-нибудь пригодится)))

Answer (score 0):

[.NET Java Interop Solutions](http://dev.mainsoft.com/)

> Grasshopper is a Visual Studio-based SDK and patented .NET to Java converter that enables you to run .NET Web and server applications to run on Linux® and other Java-enabled platforms.

Comment: Не совсем, что я хотел.

Comment: Компилятор MSIL в JVM байткод. А вы что хотели?

Comment: Конвертер исходников, не компиляция, а конвертация. Так, чтобы я преобразовал файлы .cs с реализованной логикой на C#, в файлы .java с той же логикой и смог их потом компилировать, изменять и т.д.